# Angular 14 complains that a property on my observable object does not exist

Tags: angular, ngrx

So I have declared:

```
 public userEmail?: Observable<LoggedInUser | null>;
```

then in my ngOnInit() I have:

```
this.Authstate.dispatch(unencryptEmail({ email: this.userKey }));
```

then in my ngAfterContentInit() I have:

```
this.userEmail = this.Authstate.select(selectUserInfo);
```

The premise is that a user has forgotten their password, an email gets sent with a link that includes their e-mail encrypted. So when they hit the link I first get the encryption from query params and unencrypt it in ngOnInit(). I then attempt to get the email from my state object to display it on the page.

my page has:

```
<div *ngIf="userEmail !== null">
    {{userEmail.LoggedInUser.email | async}}
</div>
```

The error states that LoggedInUser does not exist on Obervable type LoggedInUser:

```
export interface LoggedInUser {
  LoggedInUser: User,
  token?: string
}
```

my User object has the email property.

The unencrypt all works, its displaying the value passed back that is the issue.

Here is my effect:

```
unencryptEmail$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(fromAuthActions.unencryptEmail),
        mergeMap((auth) => {
          return this.authService.doUnencryptEmail(auth.email)
            .pipe(map((data) => { return fromAuthActions.unencryptEmailComplete({ profile: data });  }))
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: true }
  );
```

and my selector:

```
export const selectUserInfo = createSelector(
  getAuthFeatureState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.profile
);
```

**** Update ******

Following @Wandrille answer I changed the html bit to be:

```
<div *ngIf="(userEmail | async) !== null">
   hello
   {{(userEmail | async)?.LoggedInUser?.email}}
</div>
```

hello now displays only when the 'if' is met, but my email is not displayed. Using the redux devtools I can see that the email is populated.

Comment: To help you to understand what's going on, could you log the observable? `this.userEmail.subscribe(console.log)`

Comment: @Wandrille now that really is strange. outputting to console.log again gave the values I expected including the email.  I introduced `public userMail: string | undefined` then I replaced the console.log with `this.userEmail.subscribe(cc => this.userMail = cc?.LoggedInUser.email);` and then on my page did `{{ userMail }}`  and doesn't populate.

Answer (score 1):

As userEmail is an Observable, you need to subscribe to it in order to get the value:

For example:

```
<div *ngIf="(userEmail | async) !== null">
  {{ (userEmail | async)?.LoggedInUser.email }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, it has moved me forward, but it's still not working. I've updated my question.